# apply imported css to specific div VUEJS

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I am using Vue and Vuetify inside a WooCommerce. Everything works fine, except the Vuetify css is applied to the entire page. I just want Vuetify css to be applied to the Vue app.

The Vue app is inside this div. I guess one way is to rebuild the Vuetify css by adding this `woocommerce-MyAccount-content` class. But I don't know how to do this. I use Vue CLI 3 to create my Vue project.

Do I need to configure the webpack?

Is there another way?

`<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use stylus block level import with Vuetify styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233658/how-to-use-stylus-block-level-import-with-vuetify-styles)